# How to install Yandex CatBoost on Anaconda x64?

Tags: python, anaconda, yandex, catboost

I'v successfully installed CatBoost via

```
pip install catboost
```

But I'v got errors, when I tried sample python script in Jupiter Notebook

```
import numpy as np
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier

ImportError: No module named '_catboost'
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
```

Link to CatBoost site: https://catboost.yandex/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use python 3.5, pip maybe download not right version of wheel.
Instead of `catboost-0.1.1.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl` you need 
`catboost-0.1.1.2-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl`.

Try to reinstall catboost:
`pip install catboost --no-cache-dir`

Answer (score 5):

You can also try `conda install -c conda-forge catboost` in a conda environment