# Dependencies and packages conflicts in Anaconda?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, package

I'm using Anaconda 5.1 and Python 3.6 on a Windows 10 machine.

I'm having quite a few problems ; I tried to add some useful tools such as lightGBM, tensorflow, keras, bokeh,... to my conda environment but once I've used

`conda install -c conda-forge packagename`

on all of these, I end up having downgrading and upgrading of different packages that just mess with my installation and I can't use anything anymore after those installations.

I wonder if it were possible to have multiples versions of packages & dependencies living alongside each other which won't kill my install?

Sorry if my question seems noobish and thanks for your help,

Nate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright by searching around I was able to have everything up and running and it doesn't seem to be in conflict anymore, I had to uninstall Anaconda, reboot my computer and then reinstall it after my installation was broken though.

As long as packages and dependencies weren't messing around with each other, I was able to install lightgbm, folium and [catboost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165532/how-to-install-yandex-catboost-on-anaconda-x64) in the regular (base) environment and use them. Those were installed straight with `conda install -c conda-forge packagename`, except for catboost which I linked. Do not forget to check for the different versions of conda, python and pip (wheel) which might affect your system.

Also, `conda install nb_conda` was installed to be able to select different environments in the Jupyter notebook straight away.

I got this from [this helpful post and a mix of the answers below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085665/in-which-conda-environment-is-jupyter-executing).

Then, when I wanted to install Tensorflow, Keras, theano what worked for me are the instructions in the second top comment [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097988/how-do-i-install-keras-and-theano-in-anaconda-python-on-windows) though you should not forget to install jupyter again in the activated new environment you created.

After that, close everything, re-launch everything and in the top right corner of the Jupyter you should be able to pick the different environments and work from there.

I hope this will help someone else in the same predicament.

Comment: "*I had to...*" sorry but this answer lacks evidence to support that conclusion. So many things were changed and in a non-methodical way that one cannot determine what actually had an effect. The `nb_conda` package is a stubborn myth (only `nb_conda_kernels` is needed) and Jupyter only needs to be installed in one location (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197286/570918)). I would discourage users from following the recommendations given here.

Answer (score 8):

You could try disabling transitive deps updates by passing `--no-update-dependencies` or `--no-update-deps` to `conda install` command. Ex: 
`conda install --no-update-deps pandas`.

Comment: The problem is that different packages sometimes require different dependencies so I can't just not update them. They can't seem to all behave properly in the same environment and it drives me crazy to be honest.

Comment: +1 Solved my problem with `tensorflow` and `jupyter`. For some reason, I couldn't install any other package after I installed `tensorflow` in the conda environment - it would force me to uninstall it. This moved the unmovable object!

Comment: I still can't install `graphviz` without conflicts even with `conda install --no-update-deps graphviz`. It's ridiculous: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71968771/2745116

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to install pyrobuf library and it shew a lot of conflicts. What worked for me is

```
conda update --prefix /Users/<your_username>/opt/anaconda3 anaconda
```

Answer (score -5):

You can try using different conda environments. For example:

`conda create -n myenv`

Then you can activate your environment with:

`conda activate myenv`

and deactivate with:

`conda deactivate`

Comment: Creating a new conda environment is irrelevant to the issue at hand, which is how to resolve package conflicts in an environment.