# conda conflicts do not make sense when installing graphviz (UnsatisfiableError)

Tags: python, conda, graphviz, conflicting-libraries, mini-forge

I am fairly new to using conda. On my Apple MacBook with Silicon/M1 chip, I have mini-forge installed (conda version 4.12.0).

When trying to install Graphviz with `conda install graphviz`, I get a series on conflict messages that do not make any sense to me:

```
conda install graphviz
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package libzlib conflicts for:
graphviz -> libzlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
graphviz -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0'] -> libzlib==1.2.11[build='h90dfc92_1014|hee7b306_1013|hee7b306_1012']

Package libcxx conflicts for:
graphviz -> gts[version='>=0.7.6,<0.8.0a0'] -> libcxx[version='>=11.0.0']
graphviz -> libcxx[version='>=11.0.1|>=11.1.0|>=12.0.1']

Package zlib conflicts for:
python=3.8.5 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
graphviz -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
```

What is the error message exactly trying to tell me? That `graphviz` depends on package `libzlib`, which needs version >=1.2.11 and version 1.2.11? How is that conflicting at all? Same for `libcxx` and `zlib`; I do not see any conflicts here?

What's the real issue here and how can I resolve it?

Comment: `conda` is not always great in reporting or solving dependencies. Can you try with `mamba`?

Comment: Please also clarify: IN your question you write that you ahve miniconda, but you tagged miniforge. Which is it and which channels are set in your `.condarc`

Comment: @FlyingTeller Sorry, it's miniforge, I updated the question. I can't find my `.condarc`; there's none in my home dir.

Comment: okay, thanks for the clarification. That already says that your only configured channel should be conda-forge. Have you tried with mamba or installing to a fresh env?

Comment: Install in a fresh env works fine.